# How to bind multiple ComboBoxes to one Collection?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I Need a collection of ComboBoxes with a common collection of possible selections.

Codebehind excerpt:

```
namespace ComboBoxesInCollection
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            D = new DataContainer();
            this.DataContext = D;
        }

        private DataContainer D;
    }

    public class DataContainer
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Item> ComboboxItems
        {
            get { return comboboxItems; }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Selection> ComboboxSelections
        {
            get { return comboboxSelections; }
        }

        public DataContainer()
        {
            comboboxItems = new ObservableCollection<Item>
                    {
                        new Item(100, "Entry #1"),
                        new Item(101, "Entry #2"),
                        new Item(102, "Entry #3")
                    };

            comboboxSelections = new ObservableCollection<Selection>()
                    {
                        new Selection(1),
                        new Selection(2),
                        new Selection(3)
                    };
        }

        private ObservableCollection<Item> comboboxItems;
        private ObservableCollection<Selection> comboboxSelections;
    }
}
```

XAML excerpt:

```
    <Window.Resources>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="CSTemplate">
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,0,0" Margin="0,0,0,4" Padding="4">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Label Content="{Binding Id}"/>
                    <ComboBox 
                     ItemsSource="{Binding ComboboxItems}" //<= does not work
                     DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
                     SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedId}" 
                     SelectedValuePath="Id" 
                    />
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>

    ...            

        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ComboboxSelections}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CSTemplate}"/>
```

The ItemsControl shows the items, but the Combobox is empty.

I know that i try to access a property/collection inside of a Selection that is not existing right now.

How would i correctly specify the DataBinding so i can see the items?

Comment: The DataContext of the elements in the ItemTemplate of an ItemsControl is the associated element from its ItemsSource collection, i.e. a Selection object. In order to bind to the "parent" view model, write the Binding like `ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.ComboboxItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"`

Comment: I assume you expect to see one combobox displaying the values 1,2 and 3 ? Or is it 3 comboboxes each displaying 1,2 and 3 consecutively ?

Comment: If this is static data then you could make it a resource. You could put an observablecollection in resources with default designer data and fill it from a database  at run time. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26200.wpf-dynamicresource-observablecollection.aspx

Comment: @auburg three comboboxes displaying 1,2 and 3

Comment: @Clemens your Suggestion works and is what i was looking for, thank you! You may want to add it as an actual answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used Element Binding to access the `DataContext` Property of the window.

First Name the Window `x:Name="Window1"` and the while binding, use element binding.

```
 ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Window1, Path=DataContext.ComboboxItems}"
```

XAML of whole window

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp6.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp6"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" x:Name="Window1">
<Window.Resources>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="CSTemplate">
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,0,0" Margin="0,0,0,4" Padding="4">
            <StackPanel>
                <Label Content="{Binding Id}"/>
                <ComboBox 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Window1, Path=DataContext.ComboboxItems}" 
                DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
                SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedId}" 
                SelectedValuePath="Id" 
                />
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ComboboxSelections}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CSTemplate}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: @DennisChristian check out the solution.

Comment: i did, it works, thank you. instead of using a named reference to the window element i'd prefer to use some sort og binding Navigation, like Clemens suggested